# Default Time with MM:SS format - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have written code for countdown timer using Javascript and to make it dynamic I have given an option for admin to change the time accordingly. The javascript takes the input in MM:SS, I have used the following datatype in the model.py and the system are taking it in HH:MM format, so I cannot set the time for more than 24 minutes the values it shows are from 00:00 to 23:00. Is there any datatype or a way to resolve the time format. My application need timer in MM:SS and doesn't need hours.

*model.py*

```
class PhysicalPostPage(AbstractForm):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    strength = RichTextField(blank=True)
    agility = RichTextField(blank=True)
    flexibility = RichTextField(blank=True)
    points_for_this_activity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    timer_for_this_activity = models.TimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.time(00, 11))
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

For testing purpose, I have set the timer to 11 seconds.

*javascript*

```
function doCount(){
            var timer2 = "{{ page.timer_for_this_activity|safe }}";
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var timer = timer2.split(':');
                //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
                var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
                var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
                --seconds;
                minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
                seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
                seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
                //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
                $('#countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
                if (minutes < 0)
                    clearInterval(interval);
                //check if both minutes and seconds are 0
                if ((seconds <= 0) && (minutes <= 0)){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $('#done').show();
                    $('#countdown').hide();
                }
                timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: Why use time objects at all? You're not really treating this as a time. It's a string formatted `XX:YY`?

Comment: Are you suggesting to use CharField?

Comment: I resolved this problem by using a CharField data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by using a CharField data type. Since I was passing a string and it resolved my problem.